# invalid use of undefined type ‘struct book_implementation’

Tags: c, struct, header-files, typedef

I'm having an issue compiling my C code due to errors such as:

"invalid use of undefined type ‘struct book_implementation’"

and

"invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘book’ b = (book *) malloc (DEFAULTBOOKS * sizeof (book));"

I've created a struct and methods using it in a separate C file with a corresponding header file as seen bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "books.h"

struct book_implementation {
    int bookid;
    int amount; 
    int total;
};

//Set book IDs to books. 
void setbook( book *b, long i, generator gen){
    b->bookid = i;
    b->total = (long)gen;
    b->amount = b->total;
}
```

Header File:

```
#ifndef BOOKS_H
#define BOOKS_H


typedef struct book_implementation book; 
typedef long (*generator)();
void setbook        (book *b, long i, generator gen);
#endif
```

Here the area of the main program where the error is present:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "books.h"

#define DEFAULTBOOKS 100

long bookgen(){

    return (rand()%DEFAULTBOOKS)+1;
}

main(){
    book *b;

    b = (book *) malloc (DEFAULTBOOKS * sizeof (book));

    for(i=0; i < DEFAULTBOOKS; i++)
        setbook(&b[i], i, bookgen);
}
```

I've looked up the issue but nothing seems to fix the issue, could someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`book` is an incomplete type in your main routine. You can't use `sizeof` on it.